# Download the image from URL and change their name from google sheet and reupload image to google drive and change the original path on google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, drive

I have google sheet and contain many column the first two column image name the second column image URL (from the internet) Download the image from URL and change their name from google sheet and reupload image to google drive and change the original path on google sheet

image name and url from google sheet

[image]

Comment: Make sure to add `gooale-app-script` tag in the question tags.

Comment: Add your sheet example, take a look at [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)